# group after order

Tags: cakephp, group-by, find

In cakephp 2 I want to group table after descending order
always returned the first record of table
but I want returned last record by ordering

my data, code and result in here:

My data in table:
[image: table data]

Code in controller:

```
$books = $this->Book->find('all', array(
    'order' => array('age' => 'DESC'),
    'group' => 'name'
));
print_r($books);
```

Result after the code above:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [Book] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => ramin
            [family] => zardoshti
            [age] => 32
            [city] => semnan
        )

    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [Book] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => esmaeil
            [family] => seydi
            [age] => 30
            [city] => semnan
        )

    )

)
```

But I want this result:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [Book] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => ramin
            [family] => zardoshti
            [age] => 42
            [city] => tehran
        )

    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [Book] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => esmaeil
            [family] => seydi
            [age] => 30
            [city] => semnan
        )

    )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a virtual field on the fly to your `Book` model

```
$this->Book->virtualFields = array(
    'max_age' => sprintf('max(%s.age)', $this->Book->alias)
);
$books = $this->Book->find('all', array(
    'order' => array('age' => 'DESC'),
    'group' => 'name'
));
print_r($books);
```

The virtual field will help to get the rows with the maximum age value.

Your SQL query will look like :

```
SELECT 
    `Book`.`id`, `Book`.`name`, `Book`.`family`, `Book`.`age`, 
    `Book`.`city`, (max(`Book`.`age`)) AS `Book__max_age` 
FROM 
    `test`.`books` AS `Book` 
WHERE 
    1 = 1 
GROUP BY 
    name 
ORDER BY 
    `age` DESC
```